# Concurrency violation on one of tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have weird error, this code bellow works just fine:

```vb
Public Function queryMakerSta()
    Try
        Dim query1 As String = "SELECT * FROM kerametal.dok_sta_d where broj = 1;"
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Using connection As New MySqlConnection(konekcija)
            Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(query1, connection)
                Dim cmb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
                table.Clear()
                adapter.Fill(table)
                'Aplikacija
                table.Rows(0)("tip") = "22"

                adapter.Update(table)
            End Using
            Return True
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

But this code does not work and throws exception:

```vb
Public Function queryMakerSta()
    Try
        Dim query1 As String = "SELECT * FROM kerametal.dok_zag_d where broj = 1;"
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Using connection As New MySqlConnection(konekcija)
            Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(query1, connection)
                Dim cmb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
                table.Clear()
                adapter.Fill(table)
                'Aplikacija
                table.Rows(0)("tip") = "22"

                adapter.Update(table)
            End Using
            Return True
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

Both tables have indexes, autoincrement, etc. I'm really cracking my head around this one and can't seem to figure out why it does not work.
And both querys return single row!

Comment: We dont know the difference between `dok_sta_d` and `dok_zag_d` and the nature of "tip".  BUT you should definitely set `Option Strict On` and stop suppressing exceptions.

Comment: What table throws the concurrency error?   A concurrency error usually means that the record has changed since you last queried it and the change you're saving would overwrite it.

Comment: Since the code is exactly the same in both example, and the only difference are the tables, you'd better show the tables, and describe what you are really doing with it.